# casting Const 2d Matrix passed by reference

Tags: c, pass-by-reference

I have the following function (just frees allocated memory or 2d matrix)

```
void mat_free(Float_t  ***mat)
{
    free((*mat)[row_start]);
    free((*mat));
}
```

Note: the matrix is allocated as a single block of memory, then split to rows.

However, inside another function the mat_free is called, and i free 2d matrix as follows

```
mat_free(&A_in);
```

where A_in is 2d matrix declared as

```
Float_t **A_in;
```

However trying to free a const 2d matrix as follows

```
const Float_t **A_in;
mat_free(&A_in);
```

this does not compile and give me "error C2664: 'mat_free' : cannot convert parameter 1 from '`const Float_t ***`' to '`Float_t ***`'" . So, I tried to change `mat_free(&A_in);` to `mat_free((Float***&)A_in);` . But, this sometimes works, and other time crashes the application. This telling me that this casting is not correct. I confirmed it by running the function that calls free for multiple time and checking the memory usage (I don't think it is de-allocating the memory)

is the a way to cast a variable send to function by reference?
why the compiler does not identify this casting as an error or warning? 
thanks for any help :)

Comment: Well, the compiler did identify what you were doing as an error. That's why you had to cast it...

Comment: You should add more stars. The more the funnier.

Comment: @Falmarri : The compile caught the const issue, and that's why I am casting it. However, the compiler does not give a warning or error for doing (Float_t***&)

Comment: @rasred2004 why would it give an error? You're casting it to what it wants.